# Running a terminal command permanently

Tags: terminal, process, python, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I am currently hosting my database for free on Openshift and have my program running on a Raspberry Pi on my local network. I need to pass the data from the program to my openshift database. I want to run the linux box headless. Currently running raspbian os.

To do this I run the command:

```
rhc port-forward -a webapp
```

My question is how can I run this command permanently without it timing out (some checking to see if process is running?) and without a terminal running (background process)?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on exactly how the command works this might not be sufficient, but is usually enough to do something like this:

```
nohup rhc port-forward -a webapp &
```

`&` - run the process in the background

`nohup` - if the terminal "hangs up" (ie closes, this is a relic from the dial-up era), don't terminate the application.

Comment: Thanks! I think this would be sufficient for me needs. Do you have any way for me to check if the process is running and to automatically restart the task if its not?

Comment: You would probably want to see what name the process has in something like `ps -A`. If it's unique enough, you can use `pidof NAME` (where NAME is the name that appears in `ps -A`) to determine if it exists (something like `while true; do if ! pidof NAME >/dev/null; then INSERT_RESTART_CODE_HERE; fi; done`). If you're happy with my answer remember to mark it as accepted by clicking the grey tick under its score. Thanks!